# Show/Hide angular component based on value from top menu item clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The below creates a menu list, of three options which can be clicked like a navigation:

```
<ul>
    <li
        *ngFor="let filter of filterList"
        (click)="filterChanged($event)"
        [attr.data-nav]="filter"
    >{{ filter }}</li>
</ul>
```

Show/hide the below component based on the values of the top menu events, let's say if I have 3 options in the menu I clicked the second and third value, it should hide the below component

```
<app-test-component>

</app-test-component>
```

Should I use

```
*ngIf="filter !== 'valueA' && 'valueB' "
```

Comment: you'll have to show more of your logic, like what filterChanged() does

Comment: Bob, `*ngIf="filter!=='valueA' && filter!=='valueB'"`

Comment: @Kinglish it is just changing those three buttons and then returns the list of items when any button is clicked in the menu.

Comment: how to get the filter value out of the <li>
<p>what is the filter {{filter}}</p>

Comment: Right - there has to be something tracking the data. I guess clicking on them activates/deactivates them - but there has to be some data structure keeping values for that. `filter` isn't a variable to check. It's a single string in an array. Sounds like your click event should probably be setting a scope variable that you can use to check simply with something liek `*ngIf="showMe"` and `this.showMe` is set in your component logic

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit, this is not the best solution but from what I could understand from your question this is what I came up with.

You can refer to the link below for an working example (click on the 'li' tags)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u8oxlv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  filterList = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];
  // List of items that has been selected by clicking
  selectedList = [];
  // List of items that needs to be selected for the condition
  itemsNeededForDisplay = ['Second', 'Third'];

  // Flag to either hide or display the component
  displayComponent: boolean = true;

  filterChanged(text) {

    // If we already selected the item, we should remove it from our list, otherwise add it to the list
    const foundIndex = this.selectedList.findIndex((sl) => sl == text);
    if (foundIndex == -1) this.selectedList.push(text);
    else this.selectedList.splice(foundIndex, 1);

    // After every click we should check if we should hide or display the component
    this.handleComponentDisplayRule();
  }

  handleComponentDisplayRule() {
    // This filter will return us a new array that matches the filter (we look if the selectedList has the 'itemsNeededForDisplay')
    let foundSelectedFilters = this.selectedList.filter((elem) => {
      return this.itemsNeededForDisplay.indexOf(elem) > -1;
    });

    // If we get the length same as our 'itemNeededForDisplay' it means that our list has all the values we are looking for
    this.displayComponent = foundSelectedFilters.length != this.itemsNeededForDisplay.length;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<span> Selected: {{ selectedList | json }} </span>

<ul>
  <li
    *ngFor="let filter of filterList"
    (click)="filterChanged(filter)"
    [attr.data-nav]="filter"
  >
    {{ filter }}
  </li>
</ul>

<hello *ngIf="displayComponent"></hello>
```

hello.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code from your stackblitz link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add ngIf to your component selector and don't validate it on what value it's not but on the value it should be:

```html
<app-test-component *ngIf="filterValue == 'valueC'"></app-test-component>
```

**Additional advice:**
I suggest you keep 'valueC' in a constant within the component instead of the HTML, considering you'll reference to that value in the HTML and in your `filterChanged()` function. It'll prevent future mistakes should you want to change the value.

Then in the HTML you have

```html
<app-test-component *ngIf="filterValue == valueC"></app-test-component>
```

And in the component

```js
const valueA = 'ValueA';
const valueB = 'ValueB';
const valueC = 'ValueC';
```

***If*** your `filterChanged()` function only sets the filterValue you can also just set the value straight from the html:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let filter of filterList"
        (click)="filterValue = filter"
        [attr.data-nav]="filter">
        {{ filter }}
    </li>
</ul>
```